# checking user's current page and condition statement

Tags: php

guys im looking for a comprehensive code to check if a visitor is in index.php  then showing some lines to him

i mean i want to consider every possibility for this code

```
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}

$curentUrl = curPageURL();


if (preg_match("/index.php/",$curentUrl) || preg_match("/index.html/",$curentUrl)) {

}
```

but im looking for a more complete code to see if user is in index page of my website

Comment: A more complete? Your current one seems overkill.

Comment: why dont put the code in index.php and that sure that the user is in it ?

Comment: @Haim some sites have more than one file. And using include. Go figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this curPageURL() function has nothing to do here

```
 if ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "/index.php")
```

is enough.
But on most PHP sites index.php doesn't mean only index page. but it can be whole site too.
Without complete circumstances this question is too broad to answer.

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']
```